# Google PLAY store crash reports incomplete - missing most of the data

Tags: android, google-play

When I look at crash reports under Google PLAY's "Android Vitals - ANRs & Crashes" section, I see pages and pages of crashes from the last 30 days. Each crash type has multiple reports within it, showing the date, time, device and stack trace. The first ten crash types have over 200 instances from different devices at different times in the prior 30 days.

But when I download the crash report for the month of January (my app has a couple million downloads since last year) I get a CSV file with only 14 rows.

Anyone know where I can download complete crash or ANR data for my app in CSV format?

Comment: You can download more crash details under Google Play Console - Download Reports - Statistics - Crash Statistics. When you click on a specific report, you have the option of Overview or All dimensions. This still doesn't include all the crash raw data that's driving the Google PLAY UI

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the instructions for downloading detailed reports on [this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870).

It won't be all the data - that much of a data dump isn't that useful. The aim of the CSV reports is to help you find a statistical breakdown. The detailed logs in the Play console are to help you debug one issue at a time by showing a stack trace etc.

Comment: "As of May 2018, you can no longer download detailed reports for crashes and ANRs."